# Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('RealName') VALUES ('Louise T') WHERE SteamID='7656119801402xxxx'' at line 1

```
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "xxxx";
$mysql_password = "xxxx";
$mysql_database = "xxxx";
$prefix = "";
$conn = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
$connect = mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $conn);


$realname = 'Louise T';
$steamid = '7656119801402xxxx';

$sql="UPDATE users SET ('RealName') VALUES ('". mysql_real_escape_string($realname)  ."') WHERE SteamID='$steamid'";
if (!mysql_query($sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
```

I don't know what this is caused by? I have been checking every single word for if it were interfering with some of the MySQL commands and still seem to get this error..

This is some rules I found online:

1. You have omitted, or included an unnecessary symbol: !@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}|;:'",<>/?
2. A misplaced, missing or unnecessary keyword: select, into, or countless others.
3. You have unicode characters that look like ascii characters in your query but are not recognized.
4. Misplaced, missing or unnecessary whitespace or newlines between keywords.
5. Unmatched single quotes, double quotes, parenthesis or braces.

But I really don't think there is anything like it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your update query is invalid because `SET ('RealName') VALUES` not a valid Syntax [more details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

use update like that :-

```
UPDATE users SET RealName='$realname' WHERE SteamID='$steamid'
```

For insert :-

```
Insert into users (RealName) values ('$steamid')
```

Comment: thanks... for your support to improving my answer :) - @Drew

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get it is just me, there is a little (much) rusty. Long time since I had with SQL to do. Waow. That is embarrassing.